# Set/Get property from Swift in Unity

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity app. I would like to set/get some Swift property from Unity. Can anyone tell how can it be done?

Here is an example of how the property looks like:

```
@objc public var accessToken: String! = ""
```

Comment: This may be a good starter https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity

Comment: and why are you using ! when you have already initialised the variable at the time of declaration

Comment: Sorry for that. Just copied from some place, it's not actually a code I wrote... :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure it is exactly 1-to-1 with my case...

Comment: np. that was just a quick google nothing else